# How to approach such problems

Tags: logic

I have come across such problems, and I don't know how to approach them, universal and existential quantifiers, what I mean how do I get what is required for answering.

$\forall x \in Q, \exists q \in Z^*; qx \in Z$

Suppose we have another form:

$\exists q \in Z^*, \forall x \in Q; qx \in Z$

How do you evaluate? Are they the same? What is the answer?

Comment: The first:  If I tell you a rational $x$ can you find a nonzero integer $q$ such that $qx$ is an integer?  The answer should obviously be yes.  Supposing that $x$ is a rational number of the form $\frac{a}{b}$ then setting $q$ as $b$ makes it so that $qx = a$ is an integer.  The second:  Can you find a single nonzero integer $q$ such that $qx$ is an integer *for every* rational $x$?  That is, does the same $q$ work all the time?  The answer should obviously be no.  Suppose there was such a $q$.  What about $x=\frac{1}{q+1}$.  You would have $xq = \frac{q}{q+1}$ is not an integer.

Comment: Clear, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same: the first one is saying that for each rational number $x=m/n$ there exists a non-zero integer number $q$, which can be $n$ for example, such that $qx=\frac{m}{n}n = m \in \mathbb{Z}$. As you see this is true.

The second one is saying there exists a non-zero integer $q$ which multiplied by any rational $x$ gives an integer. Suppose such a $q$ exists. You can assume without loss of generality $q \neq \pm 1$, otherwise you get a clear contradiction. Then $\frac{1}{q^2}$ is a rational number and $q\cdot \frac{1}{q^2} = \frac{1}{q}$, which is not an integer. So the second one is false.

Comment: Clear, Thanks!!